# flutter TextFormField validation display alignment error

Tags: validation, flutter, textformfield

[image]

[image]

I have a `TextFormField` with validation on Empty.

In order to control height, `TextFormField` was nested inside `Container` widget.

Which cause unexpected side effect of displaying error message overlap as attached pictures.

to test sample code, press "Submit" to see error.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: SimpleForm(),
    );
  }
}

class SimpleForm extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
//          primary: true,
          body: Form(
            key: formKey,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 0,
                ),
//            Container(height: 0,),
                Container(
                  height: 38,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(6),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    maxLines: 1,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      hintText: 'Name',
//                  errorStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 0, height: 0),
                    ),
                    validator: (value) => (value.isEmpty) ? '**' : null,
                  ),
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text('Submit'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    formKey.currentState.validate();
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solution 1.** You can set `helperText` for the `TextField`'s `decoration` and increase the `Container`'s height:

```
Container(
  height: 60,
  child: TextFormField(
    maxLines: 1,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
      hintText: 'Name',
      helperText: ' ', // this is new
    ),
    validator: (value) => (value.isEmpty) ? '**' : null,
  ),
),
```

**Solution 2.** You can set the line height of the error message to 0 (it will be displayed above the text field):

```
Container(
  height: 38,
  child: TextFormField(
    maxLines: 1,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
      hintText: 'Name',
      errorStyle: TextStyle(height: 0), // this is new
    ),
    validator: (value) => (value.isEmpty) ? '**' : null,
  ),
),
```

Comment: You're very welcome Burak! Glad it helped! @Burak

Answer (score 2):

You can use  this

```
   TextFormField(
  decoration: new InputDecoration(
  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(                     //change border of enable textfield
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40.0)),
  borderSide: BorderSide(color: colorValue),),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(        //focus boarder
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40.0)),
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: colorValue),
        ),
                 focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
      borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1,color: Colors.red),
    ),
    disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
      borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1,color: Colors.orange),
    ),
    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
      borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1,color: Colors.green),
    ),
    border: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
      borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1,)
    ),
    errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(.                              //error boarder
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
      borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1,color: Colors.black)
    ),

        isDense: true,
        counterText: "",
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 20, 10, 0),  //padding according to your need
        hintText: "create new",
        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: colorValue, fontSize: 13)),
  )),
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer [Mobina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9902765/mobina),

Seem like issues is flutter limitation. For time being..

with border I decide to display error message on top. (Your solution :1)

without border I can display err msg as usual. (Your solution : 2)

```
// with border
            Container(
              height: 38,
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(6),
              child: TextFormField(
                textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.bottom,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  hintText: 'Name',
                  errorStyle: TextStyle(height: 0),
                ),
                validator: (value) => (value.isEmpty) ? 'hide overlap' : null,
              ),
            ),
// without border
            Container(
              height: 38,
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(6),
              child: TextFormField(
                textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.bottom,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Name',
                  helperText: ' ',   isDense: true,
                  counterText: "",
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 30, 10, 0),
                ),
                validator: (value) => (value.isEmpty) ? 'hide overlap' : null,
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove height of container it will work fine.
Here is part of my program you can take reference

```
Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.3,
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: _username,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        isDense: true,
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(45),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 6, 36, 8),
                              width: 1.5),
                        ),
                        filled: true,
                        hintText: 'Email ID',
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(45))),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value!.isEmpty ||
                          !RegExp(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+")
                              .hasMatch(value)) {
                        return "Invalid Email Format";
                      } else {
                        return null;
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

in your InputDecoration add `errorStyle: TextStyle(height: neededHeight)`